# Deriving $\sqrt2 \approx 1 + \frac13 + \frac1{3 \cdot 4} - \frac1{3 \cdot 4 \cdot34}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, real-numbers

Here is a wierd expansion for $\sqrt2$ found in the ancient Indian mathematical literature.
$$1 + \frac13 + \frac1{3 \cdot 4} - \frac1{3 \cdot 4 \cdot34} = \frac {577}{408}$$
Today we know that the resulting fraction can be obtained using [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) i.e. the recursion $\frac{P_{n-1}}{P_n} - 1$ .

Can someone explain how can we come up with that particular expansion?

Comment: In terms a continued fractions, $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,\ldots]$. $\frac{577}{408}$ is one of the convergents. For the continued fraction of quadratic surds, see Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: My guess is a greedly algorithm. Choose $a=3$ to make $1+a^{-1}$ as close as possible to $\sqrt2$; then choose $b=4$ to make $1+3^{-1}+(3b)^{-1}$ as close as possible to $\sqrt2$; then choose $c=-34$ to make $1+3^{-1}+(3b)^{-1}+(12c)^{-1}$ as close as possible to $\sqrt2$.

Comment: How could you come up with 12c.

Comment: When I chose $b=4$, that made the third term have denominator 12, so I wanted the fourth denominator to be a multiple of that 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: This is an answer for an algorithm to generate the unit fractions of the expansion :
$$\sqrt2 \approx 1 + \frac12 - \frac1{3 \cdot 4} - \frac1{3 \cdot 4 \cdot34}$$

**(an answer to the actual question is provided by Gerry Myerson in his first comment)**
$$-$$

This (signed) [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) may be obtained by starting with the 'exact' $\sqrt{2}$ and removing at each iteration the multiplicative inverse of the nearest integer of the remainder :
\begin{array} {c|cc}
x&1/x&[1/x]\\
\sqrt{2}&0.707106781187&1\\
\sqrt{2}-1&2.41421356237&2\\
\sqrt{2}-1-\frac 12&-11.6568542495&-12\\
\sqrt{2}-1-\frac 12+\frac 1{12}&-407.646752982&-408\\
\end{array}

This method may be generalized at wish...

Comment: Does this amount to the same thing as in my "greedy algorithm" comment?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Well it appears to be a (signed) [egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) algorithm and thus a greedy algorithm even if [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions) sources Lambert $(1770)$ for the signed version instead of an ancient Indian. I had noticed your comment but also your $+3^{-1}$ second term : the best unit fraction to get the nearest to $\sqrt{2}$ while I searched the nearest integer to the reciprocal of the remainder and got $2$ for $+2^{-1}$. Near but somewhat different... Cheers,

Comment: In the original post, the second term was $3^{-1}$. An editor changed it to $2^{-1}$ for reasons unclear to me. I believe that $3^{-1}$ is correct, if you want the sum to be $577/408$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I saw only the $2^{-1}$ version and as I indicated this requires the sign to be changed in front of  $\dfrac 1{3\cdot 4}$ : we have indeed $\;\dfrac 12-\dfrac 1{3\cdot 4}=\dfrac 13+\dfrac 1{3\cdot 4}$. Your answer seems to be the correct one to the initial question (and explains better the factorization of the denominators) : you should have answered! :-)

Comment: I see that the ceiling function has been used in the algorithm used to produce the series.

Comment: This is a truly beautiful method, it gives a fast converging series for $π$ , with an error of only $2.40 * 10^{-29}%$ in the fifth term $3 + \frac {1}{7} - \frac {1}{791} - \frac {1}{37,48,629} + \frac {1}{15,16,48,96,08,87,729} + ………$.

Comment: Glad you liked it @Awe Kumar Jha : the number of significant figures is doubled at each step following the number of digits at the denominators (this applies too to the usual Egyptian fractions). The drawback is that you have to know the digits of $\pi$ at the start! [Ramanujan's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Rapidly_convergent_series) is still faster for $\,\pi\,$ and $\sqrt{S}$ may be computed as quickly using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). Excellent continuation anyway,